# I am tring deploy angular project on heroku but get error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, heroku

I am trying to deploy Angular project to Heroku. I do all the steps and get An error that occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "taskmanger-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

### log error

```
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.59.2.
2022-01-06T10:03:51.565778+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user ahmedradi743@gmail.com
2022-01-06T10:03:51.565778+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user ahmedradi743@gmail.com
2022-01-06T10:03:53.260159+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user ahmedradi743@gmail.com
2022-01-06T10:03:53.260159+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user ahmedradi743@gmail.com
2022-01-06T10:11:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ahmedradi743@gmail.com
2022-01-06T10:13:13.747180+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user ahmedradi743@gmail.com
2022-01-06T10:13:13.747180+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 02b39581 by user ahmedradi743@gmail.com
2022-01-06T10:13:13.763857+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user ahmedradi743@gmail.com
2022-01-06T10:13:21.768459+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-01-06T10:13:23.031986+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-06T10:13:23.031995+00:00 app[web.1]: > taskmanger-app@0.0.0 start /app
2022-01-06T10:13:23.031995+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve
2022-01-06T10:13:23.031995+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-06T10:13:24.093017+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.
2022-01-06T10:13:24.135825+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2022-01-06T10:13:24.136043+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2022-01-06T10:13:24.141950+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! taskmanger-app@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
2022-01-06T10:13:24.142062+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2022-01-06T10:13:24.142192+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-01-06T10:13:24.142277+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the taskmanger-app@0.0.0 start script.
2022-01-06T10:13:24.142369+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2022-01-06T10:13:24.146877+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-06T10:13:24.147079+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-01-06T10:13:24.147165+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-01-06T10_13_24_143Z-debug.log
2022-01-06T10:13:24.287866+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-06T10:13:24.468341+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-01-06T10:13:24.509267+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-01-06T10:13:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-01-06T10:13:34.532068+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-01-06T10:13:36.339171+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-06T10:13:36.339188+00:00 app[web.1]: > taskmanger-app@0.0.0 start /app
2022-01-06T10:13:36.339188+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve
2022-01-06T10:13:36.339189+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-06T10:13:37.719745+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.
2022-01-06T10:13:37.735219+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2022-01-06T10:13:37.735453+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2022-01-06T10:13:37.741793+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! taskmanger-app@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
2022-01-06T10:13:37.741857+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2022-01-06T10:13:37.741926+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-01-06T10:13:37.741985+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the taskmanger-app@0.0.0 start script.
2022-01-06T10:13:37.742022+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2022-01-06T10:13:37.746924+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-06T10:13:37.747005+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-01-06T10:13:37.747056+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-01-06T10_13_37_742Z-debug.log
2022-01-06T10:13:37.913531+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-06T10:13:38.042314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-01-06T10:13:40.131198+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=task-manager-app-frontend.herokuapp.com request_id=922a2ace-cedb-4680-8cec-7a652a38d64f fwd="102.42.155.6" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-06T10:13:41.159054+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=task-manager-app-frontend.herokuapp.com request_id=43098310-85fa-4ad5-be7d-eb626eb1ab41 fwd="102.42.155.6" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-06T10:13:42.812086+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=task-manager-app-frontend.herokuapp.com request_id=ad51ff7b-521b-4aa2-ae33-708fd79d17ee fwd="102.42.155.6" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-06T10:50:35.032154+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-01-06T10:50:43.264423+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-01-06T10:50:45.594478+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-06T10:50:45.594495+00:00 app[web.1]: > taskmanger-app@0.0.0 start /app
2022-01-06T10:50:45.594496+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve
2022-01-06T10:50:45.594496+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-06T10:50:46.420060+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.
2022-01-06T10:50:46.429528+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2022-01-06T10:50:46.429724+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2022-01-06T10:50:46.433557+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! taskmanger-app@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
2022-01-06T10:50:46.433610+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2022-01-06T10:50:46.433673+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-01-06T10:50:46.433719+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the taskmanger-app@0.0.0 start script.
2022-01-06T10:50:46.433763+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2022-01-06T10:50:46.436128+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-06T10:50:46.436213+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-01-06T10:50:46.436265+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-01-06T10_50_46_434Z-debug.log
2022-01-06T10:50:46.703018+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-06T10:50:46.763378+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-01-06T10:54:06.469123+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=task-manager-app-frontend.herokuapp.com request_id=eb7f8557-007d-4196-be90-9c6eb77401cc fwd="156.222.23.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https        
2022-01-06T10:54:09.814001+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=task-manager-app-frontend.herokuapp.com request_id=c040fcf2-7e68-4fe4-8d49-4fd41f5868a1 fwd="156.222.23.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-06T10:55:51.780978+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=task-manager-app-frontend.herokuapp.com request_id=32938f3c-0639-4448-8593-1f554b88d2b0 fwd="156.222.23.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I am trying to deploy Angular project to Heroku. I do all the steps and get An error that occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `package.json` file change
this

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
  },
```

to this

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
  },
```

`server.js` this file I was created to connect Heroku with my index.html the index.html was created after building your project using `ng build --prod` in `dist` file